# How to store values in the boost multi_array container?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

I'm struggling to access the values and store them in boost multi_array container. I've tried to access the elements using the indexing methods ([] and .at()), but throws **error: no matching function for call to 'boost::multi_array<float, 2>::data(int)'**, however I can print the data (see the code) but do not have any idea how to store it and access it again for further computations. The data is two dimensional(11214, 3), but for the meantime I just want to flatten it and have a sequence of values. So my question is how to access the elements and how to store them in the container?

```cpp
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <h5xx/h5xx.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

using array_2d_t = boost::multi_array<float, 2>;
//using array_2d_t = boost::multi_array<float, 3>;
template <typename T> 
void print_array(T const& array)
{
    for (auto const& row : array) 
        { for (auto v : row)
            printf("%10f ", v);
        printf("\n"); //prints a new line similar t0 \n
    }
}

h5xx::dataset open_dataset(std::string const& filename) {
    h5xx::file xaa(filename, h5xx::file::mode::in);
    h5xx::group g(xaa, "particles/lipids/box/positions");
    return h5xx::dataset(g, "value");
}

std::vector<float> cell_from_all_frames(h5xx::dataset& ds, size_t row, size_t col) {
    // determine dataset shape: frames, particle count, space dimension
    auto ds_shape = h5xx::dataspace(ds).extents<3>();
    std::vector<float> cells(ds_shape[0]); // number of frames

    std::vector<hsize_t> offsets{0, row, col};
    std::vector<hsize_t> counts{ds_shape[0], 1, 1};
    h5xx::slice slice(offsets, counts);

    h5xx::read_dataset(ds, cells, slice);
    return cells;
}

array_2d_t read_frame(std::string const& filename, unsigned frame_no) {
    //h5xx::file xaa("../../data/xaa.h5", h5xx::file::mode::in);
    h5xx::file xaa(filename, h5xx::file::mode::in);

    h5xx::group   g(xaa, "particles/lipids/box/positions");
    h5xx::dataset ds(g, "value");

    // determine dataset shape: frames, particle count, space dimension
    auto ds_shape = h5xx::dataspace(ds).extents<3>();
    array_2d_t arr(boost::extents[ds_shape[1]][ds_shape[2]]);

    std::vector<hsize_t> offsets{frame_no, 0, 0};
    std::vector<hsize_t> counts{1, arr.shape()[0], arr.shape()[1]};
    h5xx::slice slice(offsets, counts);

    h5xx::read_dataset(ds, arr, slice);
    return arr;
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " input.h5" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    auto ds = open_dataset(argv[1]);
    std::vector<float> first_cells = cell_from_all_frames(ds, 0, 0);

    // set up multi-tau correlator for the computation of time correlation functions
    size_t nsamples = 10;            // FIXME obtain these parameters from HDF5 file. These 10 elements would be first element of first row, first element of 11214 row, first element of 11214*2 row, first element of 11214*3 row ,..., first element of 11214*10 row.
  return 0;
}
```

In the main() I read the data from function read_frame and try to pass it to the nsamples. I've tried few things but it doesn't work!!

Comment: You have a lot of noise in your **example** code. This question would be more accessible if you removed the parts not needed to reproduce the issue. One obvious thing to drop is `h5xx` -- minimize the number of libraries used. Since this is a Boost question, the code should require nothing other than Boost and maybe the standard library. Hardcode values instead of relying on command-line parameters and files. *If I understand what the question is, why have more than a wrapper supporting the definition of `array_2d_t`, a variable of that type, and an attempt to access an element?*

Comment: Yup. And then there is `int^` which makes no sense as the element type is ``float`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose.

Store it?

```
array_2d_t  frame = read_frame(filename, 1);
```

Access an element?

```
// access individual elements:
float ele = frame[0][3];

// or with index list:
std::array<int, 2> indices{0,3};
ele = frame(indices);
```

Or, as you seem to want, provide a flat view of the array:

```
boost::multi_array_ref<float, 1> sequence(frame.origin(), boost::extents[frame.num_elements()]);
fmt::print("Sum of all {} elements: {}\n",
        sequence.size(),
        std::accumulate(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), 0.f));
```

In fact yuou might reshape in-place, but then you cannot change dimensiaonality, so you get 1 "row" of all cells:

```
frame.reshape(std::array<size_t, 2> {1, frame.num_elements()});
// now the first "row" is the full sequence:
auto&& sequence = frame[0];
fmt::print("Sum of all {} elements: {}\n",
        sequence.size(),
        std::accumulate(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), 0.f));
```

There are legion options for slicing/reindex with or without strides, but I [refer to the Boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#idp18501744) to prevent needlessly complicating things here.

### Live Demo

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <h5xx/h5xx.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using array_2d_t = boost::multi_array<float, 2>;

h5xx::dataset open_dataset(std::string const& filename) {
    h5xx::file xaa(filename, h5xx::file::mode::in);
    h5xx::group g(xaa, "particles/lipids/box/positions");
    return h5xx::dataset(g, "value");
}

array_2d_t read_frame(h5xx::dataset& ds, unsigned frame_no) {
    auto ds_shape = h5xx::dataspace(ds).extents<3>();
    array_2d_t arr(boost::extents[ds_shape[1]][ds_shape[2]]);

    std::vector<hsize_t> offsets{frame_no, 0, 0};
    std::vector<hsize_t> counts{1, arr.shape()[0], arr.shape()[1]};
    h5xx::slice slice(offsets, counts);

    h5xx::read_dataset(ds, arr, slice);
    return arr;
}

std::vector<float> cell_from_all_frames(h5xx::dataset& ds, size_t row, size_t col) {
    // determine dataset shape: frames, particle count, space dimension
    auto ds_shape = h5xx::dataspace(ds).extents<3>();
    std::vector<float> cells(ds_shape[0]); // number of frames

    std::vector<hsize_t> offsets{0, row, col};
    std::vector<hsize_t> counts{ds_shape[0], 1, 1};
    h5xx::slice slice(offsets, counts);

    h5xx::read_dataset(ds, cells, slice);
    return cells;
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " input.h5" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    auto ds = open_dataset(argv[1]);
    array_2d_t  frame = read_frame(ds, 1);

    // access individual elements:
    [[maybe_unused]] float ele = frame[0][2];

    // or with index list:
    std::array<int, 2> indices{0,2};
    ele = frame(indices);

    {
        boost::multi_array_ref<float, 1> sequence(frame.origin(), boost::extents[frame.num_elements()]);
        fmt::print("Sum of all {} elements: {}\n",
                sequence.size(),
                std::accumulate(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), 0.f));
    }

    {
        // in fact yuou might reshape in-place, but then you cannot change dimensiaonality
        frame.reshape(std::array<size_t, 2> {1, frame.num_elements()});
        // now the first "row" is the full sequence:
        auto&& sequence = frame[0];
        fmt::print("Sum of all {} elements: {}\n",
                sequence.size(),
                std::accumulate(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), 0.f));
    }

    {
        std::vector<float> first_cells = cell_from_all_frames(ds, 0, 0);

        fmt::print("Sum of all {} first cells: {}\n",
                first_cells.size(),
                std::accumulate(first_cells.begin(), first_cells.end(), 0.f));
    }
}
```

With your xaa.h5 from a while ago:

```
Sum of all 33642 elements: 737589.1
Sum of all 33642 elements: 737589.1
Sum of all 75 first cells: 6053.3496
```

Comment: Thanks!! One thing more! Suppose if I just want to extract first element from all frames(total 10), would it possible to with read_frame function or it is necessary to read all frames first and then extract the element? Because the element occurs at index 0 for first frame then at 11214, so on!

Comment: There's many ways. Both h5xx and multi_array support strides as well. I just added the simplest modification of `read_frame` to do what you said: `cell_from_all_frames`. Also refactored a little bit to avoid reopening the dataset each read.

Comment: (the point is that there is nothing new, by the way)

Comment: I do not understand how you got **sum of all 75 first cells: 6053..**! I guess you take the first row of each frame and add them up

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing you!! If you look at the edited code in the question, I need to pass these elements to the nsamples(which is now 10). The dataset is continuous(row after row), but with reference to our simulation one frame consists of 11214 rows and every row represent the position of a particle in 3-dimensions. Therefore, the first row after 11214 rows is belong to that particular particle. For the moment I do not required all three dimensions, but one value from each frame. Then, 10 frames have 10 values.

Comment: **https://www.dropbox.com/s/np4zddobttbtjq0/com?dl=0**. This is the original text file. In this you can see that **1P1     aP1    1  80.48  35.36   4.25** 1P1 is first molecule and it is repeating in every frame with different x,y,z positions. I need just the x values of this molecule.

Comment: With the help of your code I can extract the x value, but I do not know how to assign this to the **nsamples**.

Comment: Please don't edit the question after it has been answered. This is not a forum, etiquette is a little different. Some people would deem this "help vampiring" (I'm starting to, honestly).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238749/discussion-between-sehe-and-rohit).

Comment: Hi! I've some issue regarding passing the values to the variable. If you could help **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69796259/how-to-pass-the-values-stored-in-vector-container-to-a-new-variable**