# How to pass the values stored in vector container to a new variable?

Tags: c++, boost

I want to pass the values contained in a vector  to a new variable. But it seems that there is something wrong in type conversion, because repeatdly it throws the error:

```
       error: cannot convert 'float*' to 'double' in 
              initialization
      error: cannot convert 'std::vector<float>' to 
             'double' in initialization
```

I've tried to change the data types of the vector and the variable, but the error keep on coming!!

```cpp
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <h5xx/h5xx.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using array_2d_t = boost::multi_array<float, 2>;

h5xx::dataset open_dataset(std::string const& filename) {
    h5xx::file xaa(filename, h5xx::file::mode::in);
    h5xx::group g(xaa, "particles/lipids/box/positions");
    return h5xx::dataset(g, "value");
}

std::vector<float> cell_from_all_frames(h5xx::dataset& ds, size_t row, size_t col) {
    // determine dataset shape: frames, particle count, space dimension
    auto ds_shape = h5xx::dataspace(ds).extents<3>();
    std::vector<float> cells(ds_shape[0]); // number of frames

    std::vector<hsize_t> offsets{0, row, col};
    std::vector<hsize_t> counts{ds_shape[0], 1, 1};
    h5xx::slice slice(offsets, counts);

    h5xx::read_dataset(ds, cells, slice);
    return cells;
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " input.h5" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    auto ds = open_dataset(argv[1]);
    std::vector<float> first_cells = cell_from_all_frames(ds, 0, 0);
    size_t nsamples = first_cells.size();
    std::cout << "no. of samples: " << nsamples ;
    double sampling_interval = 1;       // time between samples

    correlator::multi_tau_correlator<double> corr(    // TODO replace sample type
        nsamples * sampling_interval / 30        // max lag time: fraction of total trajectory length
      , sampling_interval                        // time resolution at lowest level
      , 10                                       // block size   // FIXME pass as (optional) command line argument
    );

    // define time correlation functions
    auto msd = make_correlation(correlator::mean_square_displacement(), corr);
    corr.add_correlation(msd);

    // main loop
    for (size_t i = 1; i < nsamples; ++i) {
        double position_array = first_cells();    
        //double position_array = static_cast<double>(std::rand()) / RAND_MAX;
        std::cout << "position arrays: " << position_array << std::endl;
        // append data to the correlator, which possibly computes some time correlations
        corr.sample(position_array);
    }
    corr.finalise();

    return 0;
}
```

The issue lies in *main()* function under the comment main loop. I want to pass the values stored in *first_cells* to the *position_array*, but it throws the errors mentioned above. I have tried to pass the some random numbers and guess what, it works fine!

Comment: `double position_array` is not an array, it's just one number. Not sure what you want, please add the declaration of `corr::sample` and please remove the 95% code that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @Quimby No it is just a variable name, which will be passed to the *corr.sample(position_array)*. Are you implying that position_array should be initialized a array first?

Comment: Not no, this is not Python, variables have types and those types cannot be changed throughout their lifetime. So if `first_cells` returns some type, `position_array` must have compatible type, or use `auto`. I do not know what to imply, because I do not know what kind of array you want. Based on `first_cells` I would guess `std::vector<float> position_array`  but I cannot know what type `cor::sample` accepts.

Comment: If you want it just to pass it somewhere else, then `auto position_array = first_cells();  ` will inferr the correct type for you.

Comment: **cor::sample** accepts the double type. I checked by passing the double random numbers.

Comment: That's not a good way how to check. Just read the declaration.... Okay then you cannot pass the whole array to it.

Comment: **void sample(sample_type const& sample);** this is the declaration of sample

Comment: *typedef double sample_type; *

Comment: Okay, thanks. So it cannot accept an array.

Comment: could it be possible to change *double* to some container *e.g., boost::multi_array, , uBlas*?

Comment: I do not know that, you have to ask the author of that library. But I seriously doubt they will change the type for you. Perhaps you just misunderstand what the method should do? Or why do you even need to pass it an array? Perhaps you could just pass all elements individually?

Comment: How could I pass all elements individually? Could you please provide some hint?

Comment: Well, a hint would be `for` loop. Just iterate over the vector and call the function on each element. I just feel lost in all this, you know what the code should do, right? "Discovering" just now that calling the method on each element is the desired solution sounds really weird. Usually people come here knowing what they want but are just unable to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double position_array = first_cells();
```

This tries to invoke `first_cells` (a vector) as a callable (but it doesn't implement `operator()`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Assuming that the loop variable is there for a reason, why not use it:

```
double position_array = first_cells[i];
```

Note also

- this does a possibly unwanted conversion of `float` to `double`
- if you want bounds-checking, use

  ```
    double position_array = first_cells.at(i);
  ```

The name `position_array` does suggest some more confusion. Did you actually want the three-value tupled cell instead of just the first value?

---

Getting first rows instead of first cells:

```
auto       ds         = open_dataset(argv[1]);
array_2d_t first_rows = row_from_all_frames(ds, 0);
```

Which you can use:

```
size_t     nsamples   = first_rows.size();

std::cout << "no. of samples: " << nsamples << "\n";

// main loop
for (size_t i = 1; i < nsamples; ++i) {
    auto position_array = first_rows[i];
    // double position_array = static_cast<double>(std::rand()) / RAND_MAX;
    std::cout << "position arrays: "       //
              << position_array[0] << ", " //
              << position_array[1] << ", " //
              << position_array[2] << std::endl;
    // append data to the correlator, which possibly computes some time
    // correlations
    //corr.sample(position_array);
}
```

Note that `position_array` is a sub array view from `multi_array`, so the interface is consistent with multi_array types.

Prints, on my system:

```
no. of samples: 75
position arrays: 80.03, 35.42, 4.35
position arrays: 80.19, 35.62, 4.27
position arrays: 79.78, 35.68, 4.13
position arrays: 79.51, 35.93, 4.1
position arrays: 79.44, 35.46, 4.27
position arrays: 79.5, 35.43, 4.38
position arrays: 79.03, 35.72, 4.54
position arrays: 79.12, 35.89, 4.28
position arrays: 79.04, 36.35, 3.99
position arrays: 79.06, 36.16, 4.52
position arrays: 79.22, 35.96, 4.39
position arrays: 79.07, 35.84, 4.28
position arrays: 79.43, 35.09, 4.4
position arrays: 79.38, 35.13, 3.81
position arrays: 78.87, 35.73, 4.54
position arrays: 79.3, 35.82, 4.33
position arrays: 79.38, 35.45, 3.98
position arrays: 79.5, 35.48, 3.88
position arrays: 79.16, 34.93, 4.35
position arrays: 78.86, 35.2, 4.44
position arrays: 79.15, 35.53, 4.08
position arrays: 79.41, 35.67, 3.87
position arrays: 79.83, 35.61, 4.19
position arrays: 79.63, 35.26, 3.86
position arrays: 79.94, 35.42, 4.11
position arrays: 80.32, 35.06, 4.01
position arrays: 79.99, 35.44, 3.97
position arrays: 79.82, 35.31, 4.07
position arrays: 80, 34.97, 4.07
position arrays: 80.22, 35.07, 3.91
position arrays: 80.38, 35.56, 3.92
position arrays: 80.6, 35.14, 4.11
position arrays: 80.57, 34.93, 4.15
position arrays: 80.05, 35.33, 4.46
position arrays: 80.12, 35.21, 4.2
position arrays: 80.12, 35.39, 3.97
position arrays: 80.19, 35.69, 4.18
position arrays: 80.4, 35, 3.96
position arrays: 80.55, 35.39, 4.26
position arrays: 80.52, 34.85, 4.07
position arrays: 80.57, 34.66, 4.04
position arrays: 80.69, 34.64, 4.05
position arrays: 80.94, 34.53, 3.88
position arrays: 81.12, 33.99, 4.22
position arrays: 81.25, 34.02, 4.08
position arrays: 81.68, 33.82, 4.17
position arrays: 81.75, 33.89, 4.35
position arrays: 82.2, 34.24, 4.28
position arrays: 81.83, 34.51, 4.17
position arrays: 82.17, 34.09, 4.35
position arrays: 82.33, 34.32, 4.3
position arrays: 82.65, 34.35, 4.09
position arrays: 82.44, 34.6, 4
position arrays: 82.51, 34.04, 4.41
position arrays: 82.4, 34.45, 4.34
position arrays: 81.89, 34.48, 4.18
position arrays: 81.59, 34.62, 4.14
position arrays: 81.82, 34.22, 4.34
position arrays: 81.43, 33.95, 4.05
position arrays: 81.35, 33.88, 3.9
position arrays: 81.44, 33.85, 4.24
position arrays: 81.48, 33.39, 4.25
position arrays: 81.51, 33.69, 4.16
position arrays: 81.66, 33.49, 4.34
position arrays: 82.1, 33.45, 4.17
position arrays: 82.61, 33.8, 4.07
position arrays: 82.51, 33.96, 4.5
position arrays: 82.36, 34.13, 4.46
position arrays: 82.46, 34.28, 4.19
position arrays: 82.59, 34, 4.17
position arrays: 82.26, 33.92, 4.44
position arrays: 82.2, 34.06, 4.18
position arrays: 82.24, 34.12, 4.29
position arrays: 82.16, 33.39, 3.94
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In the end I need the three value tuple, but if you think you can suggest how to implement now, that would be perfect.

Comment: Added another sketch of `row_from_all_frames(ds, 0)`

Comment: well thanks a lot!! That saves lot of time!!

Comment: I'm not so sure. I still have the strong sense I'm helping you stumble in the wrong direction faster than you could on your own. That's not something I can fix until you focus more on the "what" instead of "how". And start describing the requirements in clear terms.

Comment: I've some time constraints these days to really get to know the language deeply! But have learn a quite a lot e.g., hwo to use the API's, some of boost library and STL. I'm hoping my future questions will be more focussed on 'what' instead of 'how'!  :)

Comment: Hi! I've a some issue regarding the datatypes [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69864408/what-datatype-would-is-expected-for-the-arrays-in-c] , if you could help! Thanks!

Comment: I added an "answer" and a personal message to you, there

Comment: How to check the personal message?

Comment: Hi!  I've asked a question in personal chat.