# What datatype would is expected for the arrays in c++?

Tags: c++, boost

I've been trying to assign a datatype to the three-dimensional arrays, e.g., *double*, but keep getting the error

```
                   error: request for member 'size' in 'msd_x', which is of non-class 
                          type 'const sample_type' {aka 'const long unsigned int'}
                   -> size_t N = msd_x.size();
```

```cpp
class mean_square_displacement
{
public:
    typedef boost::multi_array_types::size_type sample_type;
    //typedef fixed_vector<double, 3> result_type;
    typedef double result_type;

    result_type operator() (sample_type const& msd_x, sample_type const& msd_y, sample_type const& msd_z) const
    {
        size_t N = msd_x.size();
        result_type msd = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
                auto dr = (msd_x[i+1][j] - msd_x[i][j])  + (msd_y[i+1][j+1] - msd_y[i][j+1]) + (msd_z[i+1][j+2] - msd_z[i][j+2]); 
            }
            // accumulate squared displacements
            msd += dr * dr;
        }
        return msd / N;

    }
}
```

Along with that it throws one more error:

```
                   error: invalid types 'const sample_type {aka const long  
                          unsigned int}[unsigned int]' for array subscript
```

I guess the way code accessing the arrays is fine. But it still throws the error. The data code reads is of double datatype, shown in the code below:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    correlator::multi_tau_correlator<double> corr(    // TODO replace sample type
        nsamples * sampling_interval / 30            trajectory length
      , sampling_interval                        // time resolution at lowest level
      , 10   
    );
    // define time correlation functions
    auto msd = make_correlation(correlator::mean_square_displacement(), corr);
    corr.add_correlation(msd);
    // main loop for all coordinates
    for (size_t i = 1; i < nsamples; ++i) {
        auto position_array = first_rows[i]; 
        // append data to the correlator, which possibly computes some time correlations
        corr.sample(position_array);
    }
    corr.finalise();

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone point out what is wrong with the datatypes?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Same error!

Comment: error: request for member 'size' in 'msd_x', which is of non- 
                                      class   type 'const sample_type' {aka 'const long unsigned int'}
         size_t N = msd_x.size;

Comment: I've no idea!!!

Comment: `msd_x` is of type `sample_type` which is of type `boost::multi_array_types::size_type` which is of type `unsigned integral`. So it's just some unsigned int type, which is a primitive type, not an object. Therefore, it has no member functions or variables.

Comment: That's also what the error tells you: `msd_x` is of type `const long unsigned int`.

Comment: Your error is in the line `size_t N = msd_x.size();`. Could you explain (in words, not code) what you believe this line is supposed to do? What are you taking the size of? What should this size be in your example code? *When you don't believe an error message from your compiler, try to prove the compiler wrong!*

Comment: *size_t N = msd_x.size()* is the total length of the array.

Comment: Aha... @TobiasBrösamle is correct. `msd_x` is a `const long unsigned int` which means that you should also be getting errors when trying to use subscripting on `msd_x`.

Comment: @Rohit *"size_t N = msd_x.size() is the total length of the array."* -- the total length of *which* array? Don't rely on linguistic shortcuts like using "the" (or "it") instead of a name. A better response would look like the following, with the blank filled in with a variable name: *"This line assigns to `N` the total length of ____ (the array)."* Doing this will feel overly verbose at first, but it is a useful technique for organizing your thoughts and finding important details that you had overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing here based on the many questions leading up to this.

It is pretty obvious that you do not want sample type to be a scalar, but a 2-dimensional array.

I will sketch a generic short-cut that would allow you to write `mean_square_displacement::operator()` to accept those, potentially even without knowing the concrete type(s) of the arguments.

### Caution

However, I want to first caution that there is no way to know whether that will work with the `multi_tau_correlator` framework that you've never described. It seems like you are trying to apply the correlator in a parallel fashion.

Firstly it's unknown whether the `correlator` framework allows you to do that (technically) and secondly it is likely not going to be fast, as this kind of parallelism is the realm of highly optimized libraries (that use actually vectorized operations like SIMD, AVX, OpenGL/Cuda).

All I see here is a raw quadratic loop, which does not bode well for efficiency.

### The blind fix

Since you don't want `sample_type` to be what you define it to be, simply define it as something else, preferrably, the thing you need it to be!

```
typedef array_2d_t sample_type;
```

There's a good chance that this is not what you actually are passing either (I suspect a sub_array view or (optionally strided) multi_array_view slice of a 3D multi array). But you can let the compiler figure it out based on the fact that you know you can index the arguments like this `arg[int][int]`:

```
template <typename Sample>
result_type operator()(Sample const& msd_x, Sample const& msd_y,
                       Sample const& msd_z) const
```

This lets the compiler deduce the concrete type, assuming all arguments have the same *statical* type. Otherwise, you can go even more open:

```
template <typename Sx, typename Sy, typename Sz>
result_type operator()(Sx const& msd_x, Sy const& msd_y,
                       Sz const& msd_z) const
```

### More Caution

I can see you're out of your depth. E.g.

- in your `mean_square_displacement` we see `auto dr` being used outside its scope. It will not compile. For the above I have GUESSED that you meant to place the accumulation into the inner loop.
- you're also **explicitly** addressing `msd_x` out of bounds (index N doesn't exist, since `N == msd_x.size()`).
- Likely `msd_y`/`msd_z` have the same extents, so they too have this issue, but even with +2
- If course the naive fix to loop till `N-2` risks [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) again unless you make sure that `N` is never <2

Here's the minimum fixes that make this code look like it might technically work, though:

```
struct mean_square_displacement {
    //typedef fixed_vector<double, 3> result_type;
    typedef double result_type;

    template <typename Sample>
    result_type operator()(Sample const& msd_x, Sample const& msd_y,
                           Sample const& msd_z) const
    {
        size_t N = msd_x.size();
        assert(N>=2);
        result_type msd = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N-1; ++i) {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N-2; ++j) {
                auto dr = //
                    (msd_x[i + 1][j + 0] - msd_x[i][j + 0]) +
                    (msd_y[i + 1][j + 1] - msd_y[i][j + 1]) +
                    (msd_z[i + 1][j + 2] - msd_z[i][j + 2]);
                // accumulate squared displacements
                msd += dr * dr;
            }
        }
        return msd / N;

    }
};
```

Comment: your answer resolve the issue with the **mean_square_displacement**, but as you pointed out above it raises the issue with **multi_tau_correlator**

Comment: If you want I can share the `multi_tau_correlator` class!! It seems that `corr.sample(position_array)` takes only single value, not the vector!

Comment: here is the main file [https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/H2Cfr86Rvn/]

Comment: `This is the multi_tau_correlator.hpp`  [https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/HJjyxXzsT8/]

Comment: `multi_tau_correlator.cpp`[https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/WKXZ4SkbDD/]

Comment: There are few more libraries , but I do not know if you want to see them :)

Comment: [https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Y2QQRPcRFP/] This is the complete description of the error